# Problema con variables POST cuando cambio el value con Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Estoy cambiando el value de un input a través de Javascript pero cuando envío el formulario la variable POST no aparece seteada.

```
function calcPrecio() {
    var x = document.getElementById("ventaPrecioKilo1").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("ventaPeso1").value;
    document.getElementById("ventaTotal1").value = x*y;
  }
```

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <form name="form" class="p-5 bg-light" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr> 
                <td>
                   <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Total precio:</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                          <div class="input-group-prepend">
                             <span class="input-group-text">
                               <i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i>
                             </span>
                          </div>
                      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="ventaTotal1" name="ventaTotal1" disabled>
                   </div>
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr> 
   </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

He intentado ya cambiar el valor en un input de tipo hidden pero eso tampoco funciona, que debería hacer?

**Actualización 1:**

Cuando recibo la variable en el controlador

```
<?php 

$var = $_POST["ventaTotal1"];
echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST["ventaTotal1"]); echo '</pre>';

?>
```

Me devuelve

Notice:  Undefined index: ventaTotal1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\marvin\vistas\paginas\matar.php on line 341

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final dio con la respuesta @JackNavaRow los campos deshabilitados del formulario no envían el valor, cambiándolos por readonly el valor calculado se refleja en el código como aparece [aqui](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#disabled)

El código ha quedado así

```html
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="ventaTotal1" name="ventaTotal1" readOnly>
```

Comment: @JackNavaRow gracias Jack!! ya he editado el comentario y puesto todo como me lo has dicho, aún soy nuevo en esto así que pido disculpas. Pero sigo sin entender por qué no puedo poner tu respuesta como la respuesta de la pregunta. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Sugiero incluir las etiquetas del `<form>` en tu pregunta y intentar explicarte mejor, sin embargo: asegúrate que formulario cuente con el atributo **method** establecido como **post**, ya que es este el que captura php.

HTML

```
<form action="archivo_que_procesa.php" method="post">
  <input type="number" name="var_name_php">
</form>
```

archivo_que_procesa.php

```
<?php
 $numero = $_POST['var_name_php']);
?>
```

Si eres nuevo quizá deberías revisar los siguientes links con información relacionada: 
[PHP: $_POST - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.post.php) 
[Developer.mozilla.org/form](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form)

Comment: Ya edite el código con las etiquetas form, el problema exactamente es ese, cuando recibo en el controlador la variable post $total = $_POST["ventaTotal1"]; no aparece ningun valor 

Notice:  Undefined index: ventaTotal1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\marvin\vistas\paginas\matar.php on line 341

Comment: cuando los campos son deshabilitados no se envia el valor, cambia el disable por readOnly [te invito a leer mas](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#disabled) la parte exacta _it cannot receive user input nor will its value be submitted with the form._

Comment: @JackNavaRow en efecto!!! eres un genio maestro, muchísimas gracias!!!